# Getting classicthesis to fit within required margins

Tags: margins, classicthesis, thesis

Our university's formatting requirements for dissertations require us to use the following margins (A4 format):

- left: 4.3 cm
- right: 4.3 cm
- top: 5 cm
- bottom: 4.7 cm

These pages in A4 format will then be cropped again to fit into a 17cm x 24 cm format with 2 cm margins on the left, right, top and bottom side.

I got this to work by adding the following to `ClassicThesis.tex`:

```
\usepackage[left=4.3cm,right=4.3cm,top=5cm,bottom=4.7cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
```

I also used the `linedheaders` option to get the chapter number to fit nicely within the margin.

However, I was wondering if there's a better way to do this? For one, given these margins, the overal font size seems a bit big now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem?  This seem to work fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[left=4.3cm,right=4.3cm,top=5cm,bottom=4.7cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Lorem ipsum}
\author{Patrick Happel}
\maketitle

\chapter{Part 1}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: It does work indeed, but I wasn't sure whether this was the right way to do it, as others have suggested using `areaset` instead, or to make changes to the .sty file to change the text-block size.

Comment: If all you want to do is lose the big (page?) number, that can probably be done using a \renewcommand to replace something in the .sty file.  Changing the usepackage itself is not recommended.

Comment: One of the remaining problems is that the bottom margin is a lot larger than the top one (that's a problem with classicthesis itself, I guess). Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Either override clasicthese using geometry or simply setting the various lengths yourself

Comment: Thanks! I actually fixed it by setting `foot=0cm` in the geometry command.